# Calling nested microservice HTTP API

Tags: microservices

We have a microservice with methods `/foo` and `/bar` (it's the very same microservices). It happened that we need to call `bar` from `foo`:

```
req --> /foo --> /bar
```

We bumped with the following issue, with big traffic: when N requests come in the same time, server register all N threads for calling the `foo` code. Then this code calls `bar`, and obviously, everything freezes, as there is no thread available to handle it.

Is there any pattern on how to deal with this situation?

(btw, I personally would not allow calling nested calls on the same context, but the decision is not mine).

Comment: It's not clear if `/foo` and `/bar` are on the same microservice or on 2 separate ones? From what you are saying it sounds like on one microservice in which case are you saying that your service is making REST calls (assuming it's REST) to itself to achieve the funcitonality of `bar`?

Comment: @AminJ same microservice

Comment: But if it is the same microservice, why are you calling `/bar` through REST? You should call it directly in code and that makes it run on the same thread and you won't be facing this problem?

Comment: @AminJ I know, see my comment in bracket :) It's not my decision. Anyway, it is because the API is built from two APIs merged, sort of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is starving itself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)). As other suggested, the only way to avoid it is to refactor your code so that the call to /foo does not make a request to /bar, but invoke directly the code of /bar.